# Evaulate and print keyboard input as a double

Tags: c

This code is not working. For every year it prints amount as 0.00 instead of the result of the calculation

```
unsigned int counter;
double amount;
double principal;
double rate;
double year;

puts("Enter the principal, interest rate as a decimal and time in years, in that order:");
scanf("%f%f%f", &principal, &rate, &year);

for(counter = 1; counter <= year; ++counter){
    amount = principal * pow(1 + rate, counter);
    printf("Amount at the end of year %u is %.2f\n", counter, amount);
```

But when I make principal, rate and year of type `float`, it prints the correct values.

Why does changing the type to `float` work but `double` does not?

Comment: Thanks hanie and Marc!

Comment: regarding the expression: `counter <= year;`  This is comparing an `int` to a `double`  this can lead to some computation problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `printf` `%f` is the correct format specifier for a double. since there is no format for a float, because if you try to pass a float to `printf`, it'll be promoted to double before `printf` receives it.

in `scanf` ,if you use `%f` means you want to read a float and `%lf` means you want to read a double. since your variables are double ,you should use `%lf` ,or it will cause undefined behavior ,because of wrong format specifier.

Answer (score -1):

The printf/scanf format specifier "%f" expects a float.  But you are using double values. So use the correct format specifier, I suggest you look it up in the printf/scanf documentation.

Comment: No. With `printf`, `%f` expects a `double` (because a `float` promotes to a `double`, so you can't even _pass_ a `float` to `printf`).